# How do you read a csv file and use that data in uwp community toolkit DataGrid? C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am beginner programmer trying to use DataGrid to show data from a csv file.
Anyone help?

Comment: You can use the CSVHelper library to read the csv file into C# objects like this simple example shows: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-class-records/

Comment: When you've achieved this, here is a tutorial to data grids: https://wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/

Comment: Ok I'll try this